# php foreach loop access value outside loop

Tags: php, loops, foreach, global-variables

Is it possible to access a value outside a php foreach loop?
For example:

```
<?php
    $array=array('a','b','c');
    foreach ($array as $value) {
}
    echo $value;
//$value is c.
?>
```

I need to access $value outside the foreach loop. 
Is this a limitation of php?
Thanks,
Ravi

Comment: `$value` is 'c', the last one, outside of loop by itself. So, what is your question? When you are outside of the loop, loop iterations are over, show the expected results.

Comment: i don't know what limitation you're taking about but that is the correct behaviour. the last iteration it assign the last element which is `c` on `$value`

Comment: Specify your question more!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment:

> I want to do is be able to access a b c outside of the foreach loop.

you can access the values in the array using the square bracket syntax:

```
echo $array[0];  // outputs "a"
```

Since PHP array is zero-based by default that means you can access the values in an array using keys starting at `0`, such as: `$array[0]`, `$array[1]`, etc.

You can learn more about how to access array values from the [relevant PHP manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Answer (score 0):

This should help you:

```
<?php
    $array = array('a', 'b', 'c');
    foreach ($array as $k => $v) {

        if($v == "c")
            $value = $array[$k];
    }

    echo $value;
    //$value is c.
?>
```

If you want to search for a specific character then this can help you:

```
<?php
    $array = array('a', 'b', 'c');
    if(in_array("c", $array))
        $value = $array[(array_search("c", $array))];

    echo $value;
    //$value is c.
?>
```

a,b,c you can access easy with this:

```
<?php
    echo $array[0];  //a
    echo $array[1];  //b
    echo $array[2];  //c
?>
```

Comment: `$value` is already 'c' after the loop. your code makes no sense.

Comment: I think as i understand his question he wants to assgin c to a variable in the foreach loop

Comment: Ok all I want to do is be able to access a b c outside of the foreach loop.

Comment: @user2648781 updated my answer how you can access the values a,b,c! Do you need further information?

Comment: @user2648781 your data is accessible through array `$array`. The request does not make any sense to me. When you are outside of the loop, there is no loop, no variable that can be set to each of the array values.

Comment: @Cheery your so right! (+1 on comment) I tried and wrote what i tought that helps him! Like how he access the array with the index. I think a basic php book wouldn't hurt xD

Answer (score 0):

It's php so I'm reluctant to say no but ... no.
It is possible as mentioned already by setting a variable defined outside the scope but the foreach has it's own local variables with its own scope.

The way you want it, trying to access a variable defined inside a foreach loop, in this case $value from the outside can lead to problems. The position in memory that is used to store that variable is free again and might have already been overwritten by something else.